# I can't seem to get Sphinx to get modules from a nexus repository

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

So I have a Python application I'm trying to document with Sphinx. I've created the directory structure, run `sphinx-quickstart`, and `sphinx-apidoc`, and changed my `config.py` for:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
```

My main problem is this error:

```
$ make html
...
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module '<module-name>' from module 'app'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'cfenv'
```

`cfenv` is a package in our pypi repository, and I have a `requirements.txt` file in both the root of the application and in the `docs/` directory that has these lines:

```
--index-url=<url for the repository>
--extra-index-url=<url for the repository>
```

The app builds and runs with no issues (i.e., it pulls the imported code from the pypi repo), but the document build fails. All the solutions I've seen have always involved putting the absolute path of the imported code into the `config.py`, but I have a URL, not a pathname.

Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Python imports work only on a file system, not from a URL. You may install a package from a URL into your file system and preferably a virtual environment, then Python will be able to import the package from there. Have you installed Sphinx and your application and its dependencies into a virtual environment?

Comment: Excellent, @StevePiercy! Installing the package from the repo into the virtual environment was the trick that did it. Thank you!

Comment: would you please accept my answer below? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python imports work only on a file system, not from a URL. You may install a package from a URL into your file system and preferably a virtual environment, then Python will be able to import the package from there.